# Need to toggle a div for each href using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me with this. I need to show course description hidden inside a div when user clicks on the course link and toggle after any link is clicked

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseID)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a title="Click to See Course Description" class="info" id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)" href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
        </td>
}
<div class="myshow" id="Calculus_show" style="display:none">
    <p>
        Information about a Course
    </p>
</div>
```

and I have my js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.info').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        id = id + '_show';
        $('div.myshow').attr('id', id);
        $(id).toggle();
    })
});
```

Here div.myshow does not show on toggle.

Comment: Please show generated html not server code. That's what the browser sees and the javascript needs to react to

Comment: Are you trying to load new information in the `.myshow` div??

Comment: @dvenkatsagar read the question...the OP has stated the content is hidden

Comment: @mambo, I think you are missing some functionality especially load new content into the div....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on the "$('div.myshow')" line you are changing the ID of the div to have a # in it for no reason, which is causing the script to break. I simply commented it out and it gave me the results you are wanting. A hide to the myshow div was also added so when a course is selected, then another course is selected, it hides the previous courses div and opens the new one's. I assumed that everything being generated in the HTML is coming out correctly when I made this.

Modified the code to show how it would work with multiple links.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.info').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    id = id + '_show';
  
    //$('div.myshow').attr('id', id);
    $('.myshow').hide();
    $(id).toggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1234
    </td>
    <td>
      <a title="Click to See Course Description" class="info" id="Calculus" href="#">Calculus</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1234
    </td>
    <td>
      <a title="Click to See Course Description" class="info" id="Programming" href="#">Programming</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="myshow" id="Calculus_show" style="display:none">
  <p>
    Information about Calculus
  </p>
</div>
<div class="myshow" id="Programming_show" style="display:none">
  <p>
    Information about Programming
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what he wants is to appear on that div only not on another div

Comment: This will still achieve that, because the ID of each link is generated by the foreach loop, and in the javascript it will use that ID to determine which div to show.

Comment: There is only one div, not many. So I think he want to show the data in `.myshow` div

Comment: The thing is that since I am pulling out data dynamically, I will have several <a> tags each with different ids...

Comment: So the ultimate result is that if I have <a>Course</a>; <a>Course2</a> etc then I want to toggle that div each time a different course is click and pulled the data for that course and display inside that div

Comment: I have modified the code to show how it would work with multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

First find all `div` that are visible, hide them. Then using `this`, navigate to necessary div and show it.

```js
$(".action").on("click", function(){
  var self = this;
  $(".info:visible").fadeOut(function(){
    $(self).parent().find(".info").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.tile, .info{
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  border:gray;
}

.info{
  color:#333;
  background:#ddd;
  display:none;
}

.visible{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile">
  <a class="action" onclick="show(1)">Show 1</a>
  <div class="info visible">Information of 1</div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
  <a class="action" onclick="show(2)">Show 2</a>
  <div class="info">Information of 2</div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
  <a class="action" onclick="show(3)">Show 3</a>
  <div class="info">Information of 3</div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
  <a class="action" onclick="show(4)">Show 4</a>
  <div class="info">Information of 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.info').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    id = id + '_show';
    $('div.myshow').attr('id', id);
    $(id).toggle();
})
```

});

Just replace above code with below code, problem is that you are adding # in the id attribute itself instead of selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.info').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id + '_show';
    $('div.myshow').attr('id', id);
    $('#' + id).toggle();
})
```

});

Hope this helps.